# Почему при миграции с foreign key Laravel выдаёт ошибку?

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-key, миграция, relationship

При миграции (`php artisan migrate`) с foreign-key вылетает ошибка:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `slien_test`.`users` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_city_id_foreign` foreign key (`city_id`) references `cities` (`id`))

Пытался сделать связь сущности `user` и его города - `city`.

Миграция `create_users_table`:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->id();
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('phone')->unique()->nullable();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('city_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');

        // new syntax
        // $table->foreignId('city_id')->constrained('cities');

        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes('removed_at', 0);
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('city_id');
    })
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
```

Миграция `create_cities_table`:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('city');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('cities');
}
```

В итоге долгие поиски причины ошибки не увенчались успехом. При чём я пробовал и новый синтаксис и старый (по документации). Сделал дополнительную миграцию `add_foreign_key_in_users_table`:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('city_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropForeign('city_id');
}
```

После команды `php artisan migrate` миграции были выполнены успешно. Я предполагаю, что ошибка вылетает из-за того, что таблица, на которую ссылается связь в таблице `users` отсутствует. Но, почему тогда никто не выносит foreign-keys в другие миграции? Все пишут в той же самой миграции и ошибок никаких нет. Как решить проблему с этой ошибкой?

**UPD:**

`users` table

[image: users_table]

`cities` table

[image: cities_table]

Comment: Показывайте структуры таблиц `users` и `cities`.

Comment: Не очень понял, какие структуры? В миграциях же описаны все необходимые столбцы. Что имеется ввиду под структурами таблиц?

Comment: Структура таблицы - это её CERATE TABLE. Результат работы запроса `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`. *В миграциях же описаны все необходимые столбцы.* Ошибка есть? есть... значит, что-то неверно. И для того, чтобы разбираться, что неверно - надо начинать именно из той точки, где обнаружена ошибка, т.е. с MySQL.

Comment: PS. Я, например, вижу, что `id` в `cities` - вот просто объявлен. Ни типа, ни чего-то ещё... тогда как он как минимум должен быть объявлен явно 1) BIGINT UNSIGNED 2) UNIQUE (как вариант - PRIMARY). Иначе не срастётся с тем, что в `users`.

Comment: Добавил скрины структуры из phpMyAdmin

Comment: Да кому они нужны, скрины?

Comment: Просто я не пишу непосредственно SQL-код. Пользуюсь Eloquent ORM которая строит запросы к базе данных. По идее по документации всё правильно, но ошибка вылетает, почему - не понятно. Скорее всего где-то ошибся я, но найти не могу. В SQL не силён.

Answer (score 2):

Какой порядок у миграций?
Сначала должна выполняться миграция для **cities**, а после уже **users** со связями.
Для этого измените метку времени в имени файла. Или создайте файл миграций **users** после городов.

Comment: А если я спроектировал БД таким образом, что чуть ли не в каждой таблице есть связи, то мне получается надо делать все связи в отдельных миграциях, чтобы при создании связей все таблицы уже существовали? По идее, в Laravel миграция `create_users_table` идёт первой всегда, и естественно, когда я запускаю миграцию с foreign-key, то таблицы cities ещё не существует. Получается, что мне придётся выносить все связи в отдельные миграции?

Comment: @ДаниилКедров, как вы написали выше у вас есть 2 варианта. Соблюдать порядок или выносить внешние ключи в файл. По моему мнению, файлы для модели **User** (модель, миграция, фабрика) выступают в качестве заготовки/примера, как и файлы с примерами тестов. Но, могут использоваться и вместе с Auth функционалом.

Comment: Понял, благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('city_id')->nullable();
$table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');

// new syntax
// $table->foreignId('city_id')->constrained('cities_table');
```

Напишите зачем это все, и от версии зависит если свежее чем 5.8 то достаточно это прописать в миграции:

```
$table->integer('city_id')->nullable();
```

Остальное пишем в модели - это отношение согласно Вашей архитектуре например:

```
public function city()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
    }
```

Comment: Я делаю по документации, синтаксис такой взял напрямую из неё (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints). Использую Laravel 7. Можно конечно использовать только связи моделей, но, если вдруг когда-нибудь понадобится использовать "сырой" запрос к БД, без участия моделей, то БД не сможет выполнить этот запрос. Поэтому, как я понимаю, лучше сделать связи и в моделях, и в миграциях. Если я не прав, поправьте пожалуйста.

Comment: При помощи Join когда нужно можно работать и без этого, если честно не могу в данной ситуации представить как может понадобится сделать сырой запрос к бд, когда у вас отношение User к City и куча куча встроенных выборок и методов коллекций LARAVEL от count() до groupBy(), делайте как я написал, это избыточно и сырые запросы вам там не пригодятся это 100 тысяч процентов.